# how to parse string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

im trying to parse the following string;

```
"data[Product][0][fieldname]"
```

i need to be able to change the "[0]" part to a number, the "data[Product]" wont change while the "[fieldname]" will change.

im not sure how to do it with javascript but have an rough idea.

all i have which is wrong, is below but since [0] varies each time it doesnt work;

```
name="data[Product][0][fieldname]";
name.replace('[0]', '['+newrowid+']'
```

Jsfiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzy_dunlop/8WKcs/

Comment: you need to iterate that field? I mean it can be [0], [1] ... etc?

Comment: Is this part of an input name attribute, or a JavaScript object that should be parsed as a real object?

Comment: This is one of those questions that makes me think that, if we could "zoom out" a little, a far, far better overall solution could be found.

Comment: you are right @Pointy , i'm sure there is a lot of "bad" design behind that , but i guess the regexp solution will be the one that suits the question's author needs...

Comment: its part of a jquery clone table row method,the "[0]" part will change on each function call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regexp:

```
var a = "data[Product][0][fieldname]";
var re = /(.*\[.*\]\[)(.*)(\]\[.*\])/gi;  

newstr = a.replace(re, "$1" + "YourString" + "$3");  
document.write("Now: " + newstr);
```

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/NKbd9/1/

Comment: I was going to be even more specific with the regex: `^data\[Product\]\[(\d*)\]\[(\S*)\]$`  You beat me to it, because I couldn't remember the exact syntax for working with regular expressions in javascript. ;)

Comment: More specific would be better, if the failure would be properly caught. I would agree with fixing the "Product", since he specified that in his question. However the \d and \S are assumptions of our part which might one day break the code, since no full specs are available.

Comment: And though the regexp is so very close to my beloved Perl, I too used JSFiddle not only as a service to the question asker, but also as a way for myself to double-check here ;]

Comment: @fuzzydunlop Do you understand the regexp? You see how we split the string in three parts using the `(` and `)` in the regexp, and how we put parts 1 and 3 back together, but change part 2? (It would be even more efficient to not capture part 2, and just glue the captured parts together, but you see how it works here).

Comment: Totally agree that \d and \S were assumptions. I should have mentioned that when I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
name = name.replace('[0]', '['+newrowid+']');
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace can take a regular expression instead of a string.

Try this:

```
name="data[Product][0][fieldname]";
name.replace(/\[\d\]/, '['+newrowid+']');
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to do this inside a loop, in that case you just need to make it dynamic. Also not that replace doesn't change the current string, it returns a new string so you need to assign the value returned back to name.

```
    var i = 0, 
        len = 10,
        name,
        newrowid = 13;
for(; i <len; i++) {
    name = "data[Product]["+i+"][fieldname]";
    name = name.replace('['+i+']', '['+newrowid+']');
}
```